# assign value to numpy arrary

Tags: python, numpy

I initialize

```
Tcoords = np.array([0,0])
```

and

```
Tcoords[0] =.1
```

but why when printing Tcoords still

```
Tcoords
array([0, 0])
```

Comment: Try printing the dtype of `Tcoords`.  It's likely `'int64'`.  You should initialize it with float zeros or `dtype='float64'`.

Comment: be careful with the data type. You (implictly) declared an integer array. And then set a double value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assigned `0.1` will be cast into an integer. Use:

```
>>> Tcoords = np.array([0,0], dtype=np.float)
>>> Tcoords[0] = .1
>>> Tcoords
array([ 0.1,  0. ])
```

This is what happens:

```
>>>int(0.1)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use float instead of int. It will work:

```
Tcoords = np.array([0.0,0.0])
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I edited my answer. Thanks a lot!